# powershell web.deploy.cmd positional parameter

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, webdeploy

I'm having big issues with powershell, web deploy and escaping command paths. I'm trying to run a powershell script before the deployment using the runCommand provider in Web Deploy. However, powershell seems to interpret paths with spaces as seperate parameters even when I encase in double-quotes.

This is what is output if I run

```
web.deploy.cmd /y

Info: Updating runCommand (powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass invoke-command "C:/local dev/mobile/Core/Web services/wsAuthUser/mobilestability/src/wsAuthUser/obj/Debug/Package/PackageTmp/install/installboot.ps1" -computername server01 -argumentlist Mobile2/AuthUser, pre).
```

But the error is:

```
Warning: Invoke-Command : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts a
gument '

Warning: dev/mobile/Core/Web'.
At line:1 char:15
```

Why is it complaining when the whole path is in quotes?

**Update:**

If I paste the following into Powershell ISE:

```
invoke-command "C:\group dev\mobile\Core\Web Services\wsAuthUser\mobilestability\src\wsAuthUser\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\bin\install\installboot.ps1" -computername dev-mob2iis01 -argumentlist Mobile2/AuthUser, pre
```

It runs fine with no errors.

If I then open a Command prompt, past the same command but pre-pend with powershell and the execution policy parameters like so:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass invoke-command "C:\localdev\mobile\Core\Web Services\wsAuthUser\mobilestability\src\wsAuthUser\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\bin\install\installboot.ps1" -computername server01 -argumentlist Mobile2/AuthUser, pre
```

It fails again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is windows, not unix. So you would use backslashes for file paths, not regular slash.

Update:
You just gotta play around with the quotes to make it work through cmd

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command "invoke-command 'C:\localdev\mobile\Core\Web Services\wsAuthUser\mobilestability\src\wsAuthUser\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\bin\install\installboot.ps1' -computername server01 -argumentlist Mobile2/AuthUser, pre"
```

Comment: I've just tried with back slashes and also double back slashes and I get the same error??

Comment: `"C:\local dev\mobile\Core\Web services\wsAuthUser\mobilestability\src\wsAuthUser\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\install\installboot.ps1"` ... no reason that shouldn't work, do a `resolve-path` to make sure it exists

Comment: ok, it should have been \bin\install\installboot.ps1 - but this has made no difference to the error. Powershell sucks when it doesn't work! I've spent a whole day messing with this. The error is definately splitting the path after 'local dev'

Comment: I could say try `invoke-command -Filepath "C:\path to\file\script.ps1"` .. but I am confused what your error is or what command your trying to run at this point. Maybe update your post with more info so I can help

Comment: I've updated my post above. For some reason running from command line with some extra parameters at the beginning causes the issue.